# Single styles.js file in a React Native application — any cons?

Tags: react-native

Most examples that I have seen have multiple styles.js files.
Is there an drawback (performance) to holding all definitions in a single file?

The advantage of this is, obviously, sharing common styles among all components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

importing unless files affect your performance, that's why some of the libraries are used as dynamic import which is very useful for big modules like camera accessibility package and all

similarly  importing a style which contain all the styling is bad if app is bigger in size but its okay with small apps like 1-2 screen

for more ref. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#inline-requires

Answer (score 0):

you can create any const value file like color ,dimens ,and styles .
here an example of style.js that can hold all of your styles:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
export default style = [

    st_1 = StyleSheet.create({
            subStyle_1 : {backgroundColor: 'red'},
            subStyle_2 : {backgroundColo: 'blue'}
    }),

    st_2 = StyleSheet.create({
            subStyle_1 : {backgroundColor: '#fff'},
            subStyle_2 : {backgroundColor: '#000'}
    }),
]
```

then you can import this to other js files:

```
import my_styles from 'PATH_TO_STYLE.JS'
```

and call them like this:

```
<View style={ my_styles.st_1.subStyle_2 } /> //returned {backgroundColo: 'blue'}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was not the question. The other answer is answering what I asked...